# Reporting available RDP sessions

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp

Default Windows 2003 Server has two RDP sessions available.If all of them are taken by someone else you will only be notified about it after providing your credentials.
This seems like a waste of time especially in our environment where we share a lot of development server.
Could a message be given as soon as you open the connection window  if the connections are taken up? We can use qwinsta  based script to check sessions before logon but it's still takes time.

Is there a feature to do what I am asking for?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way that will suit your needs, but there are actually 3 RDP sessions available if you use the /console switch when conecting to one of them.

Comment: I have tried connecting to console already.Unfortunately I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Sysinternals has a utility called [psloggedon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897545.aspx) that will list who is logged onto a remote computer. It probably isn't much better than your qwinsta based stuff though.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal Services Manager will show you all the active/disconnected sessions.  You can either run it on one of the servers or copy tsadmin.exe from windows\system32 to your local machine (remember to run it as a domain admin)